# Pandas returning object type instead of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('Fortigate-Inbound traffic from blacklisted IP.csv')
df2= df[df['Device Action']=='Accept']
df3 = df2.groupby(['Destination Address', 'Sum(Aggregated Event Count)'])
print(df3)
```

Which returns pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000016F627C3208 instead of the actual values in the dataframe. How can I get it to print the values?

Comment: You would benefit from reading the documentation about pandas.

Comment: It's printing a *groupby object*, which is exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: Do you just want to see the groups or do you want to do some aggregation (sum of a column for each group, size of a column for each group etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [aggregation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation) by `sum`:

```
df3 = df2.groupby('Destination Address', as_index=False)['Aggregated Event Count'].sum()
```

Sample:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Destination Address':['a','a','a', 'b'],
                   'Aggregated Event Count':[1,2,3,4]})
print (df2)
   Aggregated Event Count Destination Address
0                       1                   a
1                       2                   a
2                       3                   a
3                       4                   b

df3 = df2.groupby('Destination Address', as_index=False)['Aggregated Event Count'].sum()
print (df3)
  Destination Address  Aggregated Event Count
0                   a                       6
1                   b                       4
```

Another solution:

```
df3 = df2.groupby('Destination Address')['Aggregated Event Count'].sum().reset_index()
print (df3)
  Destination Address  Aggregated Event Count
0                   a                       6
1                   b                       4
```